# How can I find the "real" difficulty on testnet?

Tags: bitcoind, difficulty, testnet

As is well known, testnet has a "20-minute rule": if no block is found within 20 minutes, the mining difficulty drops to 1 until a block is found.

From some experimentation, it appears that bitcoind's `getdifficulty` function reports the difficulty of the most recent block.  Thus, if the most recent block was mined under the 20-minute rule, `getdifficulty` returns 1.

In this case, how can I find the "real" difficulty level?  That is, the difficulty that would be required of a block submitted less than 20 minutes after the previous one?

The best approach I have found so far is to follow the blockchain back until I find a block with a difficulty other than 1 (or less than 20 minutes after the block preceding it).  But this will be prone to error if a difficulty adjustment has recently taken place.

bitcoind must know the real difficulty at all times; can I query it?

Comment: Why would bitcoind always have to know it? If the 20-minute-rule is hard, bitcoind will just accept any new block it receives after 20 minutes.
But I never heard of this rule, can you point out where you found out about it?

Comment: @StevenRoose: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Testnet: "In addition, if no block has been found in 20 minutes, the difficulty automatically resets back to the minimum for a single block, after which it returns to its previous value."

Comment: @StevenRoose: If bitcoind receives a block that's less than 20 minutes newer than the previous one, it needs to use the "real" difficulty in deciding whether to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `getblocktemplate` RPC command and look at the `target` field.