# bitcoin-0.9.3 won't syncup on TESTNET stuck at height 26859

Tags: bitcoind, testnet

Downloaded the latest bitcoin core tar ball 0.9.3.
New install for test and development. This thread relates only to the TESTNET, I haven't tried on the production network.
When launching the bitcoind everything works as expected until it reaches block at 26859 where it stops adding blocks. Nothing happens after no more blocks are requested.
After some debugging, it appears that the next block 26860 contains a transaction that fails verification, so it won't validate the block. These blocks (that are failing) are more than 2 years old, but I didn't expect to hit this hurdle so early in the game. Can anybody shed some light ? Am I doing something wrong here? DOwnloaded the bitcoin tar from the official web site and checked the signature.

Anyone can easily reproduce this on the testnet network.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: That's really early. You can try deleting the latest block (blk00xxx.dat file) in .bitcoin/testnet3/blocks and restart bitcoind?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Using ubuntu 14.04 and bitcoin version 90300, protocol version 70002 and I've set txindex=1

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally sure why it failed on height 26859, but I upgraded to 0.9.4 (from 0.9.3) using:

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade bitcoind
```

then I deleted the testnet3 folder and fired up bitcoind and now it's working and has passed height 26859.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. There was a not so obvious patch I had to apply to get v0.9.4 to compile.

Comment: The instructions above are for people using the PPA.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I can assist you directly. I compiled the code myself from the Github bitcoin/bitcoin [site](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin).

Just compiled bitcoind for OSX 10.9 and 10.10.  Notice that the results below are for v0.9.4. Here are the "getinfo" results I get for the testNet. (FYSA - had to apply a soft link so that I didn't have to supply a fully qualified file path name.)

```
Skaht% bitcoin-cli -conf=testNet.conf getinfo
{
    "version" : 90400,
    "protocolversion" : 70002,
    "walletversion" : 60000,
    "balance" : 0.00000000,
    "blocks" : 322742,
    "timeoffset" : 0,
    "connections" : 1,
    "proxy" : "",
    "difficulty" : 1.00000000,
    "testnet" : true,
    "keypoololdest" : 1423202150,
    "keypoolsize" : 102,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "relayfee" : 0.00001000,
    "errors" : ""
}
```

Its a little disturbing to see the difficulty factor is shown to be one. However, when I issued a "coin" RPC to the bfgminer connected to the testNet bitcoind I received a valid difficulty factor.

Comment: Yes looks like the pb was fixed in 0.9.4 and later.

Comment: I know why it was stuck, block 26860 had a transaction that couldn't be verified (0.9.3 version), that's why  it would never sync the rest of the blocks.

Comment: For the reason why the difficulty appeared as 1, see http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/18554/how-can-i-find-the-real-difficulty-on-testnet.